# How to perform nonclustered index seek instead of clustered index scan

Tags: sql-server, database, t-sql, indexing

I test the benefits of nonclustered indexes.

I use db AdventureWorks
When i execute the query:

```
SELECT [address].City, [address].[AddressLine1] 
FROM [AdventureWorks].[Person].[Address] as [address]
WHERE [address].City = 'Seattle'
```

I see in execution plan tab

```
/*
Missing Index Details from SQLQuery3.sql - 
The Query Processor estimates that implementing the following index could improve the query cost by 97.9636%.
*/

/*
USE [AdventureWorks]
GO
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [<Name of Missing Index, sysname,>]
ON [Person].[Address] ([City])

GO
*/
```

And  i see in the execution plain tab icon "Clustered index scan" and i know that it is bad because index seek is better

But when i execute query

```
USE [AdventureWorks]
GO
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX CityIdx
ON [Person].[Address] ([City])

GO
```

**I still see the in execution plain tab "Clustered index scan". WHY not "Clustered index seek" ? Does it should be "Clustered index seek" ? IN which cases it should be "Clustered index seek".**

Comment: is 'clustered', not 'clastered'.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are hitting the [index tipping point](http://www.sqlskills.com/BLOGS/KIMBERLY/category/The-Tipping-Point.aspx): there are simply too many entries with `City = 'Seattle'` to bother seeking, for each one, the `AddressLine1` in the clustered index. One approach, for *this* particular query, is to include the projected column:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX CityIdx
ON [Person].[Address] ([City])
INCLUDE ([AddressLine1]);
```

But that hides the *real* issue, namely *why* are are you interested in selecting *all* rows on such a non-selective predicate? The application should not make such requests.

Comment: Why it not selective predicate?

Comment: Because selecting on the predicate `City = 'Seattle'` will return many entries.

Comment: What i should do in that case to retrieve all rows with city 'Seatle' using  index?

Comment: Again, the real question is: why do you need all the rows with with city Seattle for?

Comment: For testing, does not exists any cases in which it query will be used?