# Index scan instead of index seek

Tags: sql-server, non-clustered-index

I have a table with 44 columns, with around 80 million rows. My use case requires to have a select of all these columns based on conditions of 5 columns (col1, col2, col3, col4, col5). I've created a nonclustered index as follows

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_index] ON [dbo].[Table]
(
  [col1] ASC,
  [col2] ASC,
  [col3] ASC,
  [col4] ASC,
  [col5] ASC
)
INCLUDE(col6, col7,... col44)
```

Whenever I try to do something like this:

```
SELECT col1,... col44 FROM Table WHERE col1 = 0
```

The query is performed using an index seek non-clustered. However, any other `SELECT` based on any combination of other columns (different than 1) results on an index scan:

```
SELECT col1,... col44 FROM Table WHERE col2 = 0
```

My understanding from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12155514/2026277) is that I might have hit the index tipping point. However, the number of columns returned when the condition is `col1 = 0` is 7 millions (here, SQL Server uses an index seek), whereas the number of rows returned by the condition `col2 = 0` is far fewer (around 200k rows), and here, SQL Server uses an index scan. Also, if I try to find rows where `col2 = 1`, the result is 0 rows... And yet in this case an index scan is performed instead of a seek.

One of the key columns (col5) is a datetime, and I'm also trying to do a `SELECT` that retrieves the rows form the last day (which a very small of rows, around 20k) and SQL Sever also doesn't use the index seek.

So I don't understand why SQL is not capable of using an index seek. Is there anything wrong with the index?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The index is sorted in the order of the columns you defined. The index isn't helping as the first sort is on `col1` and your clause is on `col2`. Just like a phone book is sorted in last name and first name order. So, if you were asked to get all the people is it who had the name Brown, and first name started with T, you;d find it easy. That same index won't help you, though, if you're asked just for all people who's first name started with T.

Comment: Thanks @Larnu So if I wanted to do selects based on my 5 key columns, should I do 5 different indexes, one for each column, and including all of them the 44 columns?

Comment: If you include all the other columns in every index it would mean you basically have 6 copies of the table.  That might improve the performance of your select queries, but updates/inserts/deletes will take a lot more time.

Comment: How many of the 80 mio rows are usually returned when you select the data?

Comment: Thanks @Wouter During my tests, around 50k-100k rows every time I run the query. But my final purpose is to join this table with another one where the conditions involve these 5 columns